# Oracle database concat column

Tags: database, oracle, concatenation

***Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0*** 
Someone who could help me with my query Oracle

```
    **TABLE A**         **TABLE B**           **TABLE usuarios**

  RU                  RU       DESCRIP      iduser
==================  ====================  =======================
| adm            |  | adm   | hi       |  |  1                  |
| adm            |  | adm   | help     |  |  1                  |
| adm            |  | adm   | me       |  |  1                  |
| usr            |  | urs   | good day |  |  1                  |
| rhm            |  | rhm   | s        |  |  1                  |
```

**table usuario** is reference >> **Table A** and **Table A** reference >> **Table B**

this is my query and 
the result of this is

adm = hi,hi,hi

```
SELECT case row_number()
over (partition by A.ru by B.descrip) WHEN 1
THEN A.RU
END as RU,
LISTAGG(B.descrip, ', ') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.RU) "names"
FROM A
INNER JOIN usuarios on usuarios.iduser = A.iduser 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.RU = A.RU
WHERE A.iduser = 1 
GROUP BY A.RU, B.descrip 
ORDER BY A.RU, B.descrip
```

and i need this result

```
RESULT 

adm = hi help me
usr = good day
rhm = s
```

Comment: I'm afraid your table B is missing some important information about the _order_ which each description term should take.

Comment: In addition to Tim's question (how do you determine in what order to concatenate the values?) there are at least two additional important questions. (1) What version of Oracle do you have? Different tools are available in different versions. Don't guess; run `select * from v$version` and report back with the full (five-part) version, like 12.1.0.2.0. (2) Is it possible that the result of concatenation would be very long (over 4000 bytes)? What tools you need will depend heavily on this.

Comment: In your existing code, the first thing that stands out (and causes the unexpected result) is that you group by `ru` **and by** `descrip`. You should not group by `descrip`.

Answer (score 0):

this is my new query

```
SELECT  A.RU,
LISTAGG(B.descrip, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B.descrip)
over (partition by A.RU) B
FROM A 
inner join usuarios on usuarios.iduser = A.RU
left join  B on B.RU = A.RU
where      A.iduser = 1
GROUP BY A.RU, B.descrip
order by A.RU, B.descrip;


table result
=================
 RU      descrip      
=================
adm    hi help me
adm    hi help me
adm    hi help me
usr    good day
rhm    s
```

i need just

```
adm  hi help me
usr  good day
rhm  s
```

Answer (score 0):

CORRECT QUERY:

```
select distinc * from (
    SELECT  A.RU,
    LISTAGG(B.descrip, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B.descrip)
    over (partition by A.RU) B
    FROM A 
    inner join usuarios on usuarios.iduser = A.RU
    left join  B on B.RU = A.RU
    where      A.iduser = 1
    GROUP BY A.RU, B.descrip
    order by A.RU, B.descrip
);
```